# Open / Close Div Tags After Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am just learning Jquery and I am trying to do something that I think is possible, but I am not sure.

I have a div tag that contains a form and it's target is an Iframe. When a user clicks submit on the form and the Iframe is loaded, I want to hide the div tag that contains the form and I want to show two div tags that are hidden.

Thanks for the help.

Here are the div tags. I also posted the div tag container that loads an animation while the Iframe is loading incase that would be helpful.

```
<div id="form" style="visibility:visible">
    <form id="form" method="post" target="iframe1" convert.php">
        <input id="element_1" type="text" maxlength="255" value="http://"/> 
        <input id="saveForm" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
</div>

<div id="hidden1" style="visibility:hidden">
    <p>hidden content</p>
</div>

    <div id="hidden" style="visibility:hidden">
    <p>hidden content</p>
</div>


<div id="frameWrap">
    <img id="loader1" src="ajax_loader_blue_512.gif" alt="loading gif"/>  
      <iframe id="iframe1" name="iframe1" src="1.html"  onload="hideLoading()"> 
      </iframe>
</div>
```

This is the script I am using for loading the animation:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#iframe1').on('load', function () {
    $('#loader1').hide();
});
});
// in ready()
$('#form_710370').submit(function(){$('#loader1').show();return true;});
</script>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/hide/ and http://api.jquery.com/show/

Comment: The solution of UDB function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*suggestion:-* use different ids for `div` and `form`

```
$('#form').submit(function()

{
    $(this).parent().hide()
    $('#hidden1, #hidden').show()
})
```

Comment: Hi I tried it in a fiddle and it does not seem to work. [link]http://jsfiddle.net/mikeef74/3j5mn/[link]

Comment: I meant to say that it is hiding the whole page and not opening the hidden divs, as you can see in the fiddle.

Comment: @MichaelFalciglia  *suggestion No2:-* there were many errors so a friendly advice- learn `HTML` properly and start from `javascript` first then move to `jquery` basics (refer good books not just online material) .jsfiddle.net/UD_B/3j5mn/2. And also learn to use jsfiddle and last, **JSFIDDLE** is not for server side scripting

Comment: I know you can't have two IDs on a page, I just copy & pasted the 1st div and forgot to change the ID. I know HTML/CSS very well, not good with JS, but most of my developer friends told me to just learn jquery and that is what I am trying to do. They suggested I ask questions on here and so I am.